# How to call "geth attach" on --testnet better than writing full path?

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to connect to my running `geth --testnet`.

If I run `geth --testnet attach`, just like `geth attach` I get :

`Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /user/.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory`

Which is normal, because `geth.ipc` is not in `.ethereum` but in `.ethereum/testnet`.

Is there a way to use an option to make geth look for `geth.ipc` in the right folder when I'm using the testnet ?

It can be a little heavy to write full ipc path every time (Right now I use `geth attach ipc:/path/to/ipc` and often start it by hand).

Edit:
I found [an open issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2502) on github that suggests there is no way to use options with `attach` yet. I'm now only asking for ways to do it faster than writing full path.

Comment: Try: `geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have an alias on my computer (Linux) that lets me do this quickly. I just put

`alias gat='geth attach ipc://${HOME}/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc'`

in my `.bashrc`.

You could also, alternatively, alias geth itself, i.e.

```
alias geth='geth --ipcpath ipc://${HOME}/.ethereum/geth.ipc'
```

so that the ipc file is placed in the default location regardless of which network you are using. You can always call `\geth --args` if you want to use the raw command without the alias.

On windows, I believe you can use

`doskey gat=geth attach ipc://%APPDATA%\Ethereum\geth.ipc` or something of the sort

Comment: seems like `-ipcpath ` flag does not exist with the latest `geth`

Answer (score 7):

You can specify where to create ipc file and where to find it while attaching:

```
$ geth --testnet --ipcpath /tmp/geth
$ geth attach /tmp/geth
```

Another option is to attach via HTTP-RPC:

```
$ geth --testnet --rpc
$ geth attach http://:8545
```

Please note, only `eth,net,web3` API modules are provided via HTTP-RPC by default. You need to specify additional modules explicitly if you require them:

```
$ geth --testnet -rpc --rpcapi "admin,eth,miner,net,personal,web3"
```

Comment: +1 for `geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545`

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the ipc path with the `--ipcpath "/path/to/my/geth.ipc"` option

```
--ipcpath "geth.ipc"     Filename for IPC socket/pipe within the datadir (explicit paths escape it)
```

Comment: I'm looking for a quicker method. My path is pretty long and not default, and I often have to type it by hand. I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: use linux variables to set your path exp : export IPC_PATH="/var/......"
next time use $MY_PATH

Comment: seems like `-ipcpath`  flag does not exist with the latest geth

Answer (score 2):

or

if you can learn from log

```
INFO [03-19|15:31:25] IPC endpoint opened                      
url=/Users/XXXX/dataEth2/geth.ipc
```

then

you can  `geth attach ipc:/Users/XXXX/dataEth2/geth.ipc`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a nuclear option, but you can create a symlink called `geth.ipc` in `.ethereum` which points to the actual, testnet `geth.ipc`. I can confirm this works, as I've done this myself.

Comment: That's interesting. What happens if `geth --testnet` is closed and someone opens `geth` ? Will it replace the symlink ? Or if geth is closed so geth.ipc doesn't exist, but the symlink does ? Do we get a standerd error ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I use it because my datadir is on another partition (though I realize I probably could have just symlinked the whole directory). The symlink will definitely still exist if there's nothing it points at.

Comment: I myself have symlinked my whole `.ethereum` folder to another disk, it works great !

Answer (score 1):

You can add `--rpc` in geth command line

and then you can attach with `geth attach http://localhost:8454`.

Comment: Try to understand the question and then answer. Try to be more explanatory, and avoid spell mistakes.

Comment: Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: Post "http://localhost:8454": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8454: connect: connection refused

Answer (score 0):

Since you will normally only run the testnet or the main net - why not fix your ipc always in the same place in the main call to geth? 
Then geth attach (and MIST) knows where to look for it....

Comment: How do I do that ? `geth.ipc` is created automatically when I run geth and deleted when I close it.

Comment: you can set the ipcpath with the --ipcpath flag so create a script that runs the testnet but uses the standard path.